# How to target a div with a class and an inner p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a structure that looks like this..

```
<div class="infobubble">
    <a href="#" class="btn-closebubble"></a>
    <p>
PLACE CONTENT HERE
</p>
</div>
```

How do I use jquery to target the in

tags?

I tried this but did not work.

```
$("infobubble p").html('My Text');
```

Comment: I did not indent ...thats why the code did not show up.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is wrong, you need to specify that you are looking for a class, like so

```
$(".infobubble p").html('My Text');
```

Your code `$("infobubble p")` would be looking for a tag element named `infobubble` which does not exist

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".infobubble p").html('My Text');
```

in jQuery you need to add an '.' to select by class or '#' to select by id.
If no '.' or '#' is specified, jQuery will try to find an element by tag name... in your case it was trying to find `<infobubble>` which isn't an element.